# What does the C# compiler mean when it prints "an explicit conversion exists"?

Tags: c#

If I make an empty test class:

```
public class Foo
{
}
```

And I try to compile code with this statement:

```
Foo foo = "test";
```

Then I get this error as expected:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Foo'

However, if I change the declaration of `Foo` from class to interface, the error changes to this (emphasis mine):

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'string' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Foo'.
>   **An explicit conversion exists** (are you
>   missing a cast?)

What is this "explicit conversion" which is supposed to exist?

**update**: the issue is a bit more subtle than I initially thought. To reproduce it, put this code in a new console application in Visual Studio 2008:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Foo
    {
    }

    interface IFoo
    {
    }


   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Foo b = "hello";
      }
   }
}
```

Visual studio will automatically show the correct error at this point (before you build the code). Now insert the "I" to turn "Foo" into "IFoo" and **wait a few seconds without building**. The "explicit conversion exists" version of the error will now appear automatically in the error output window and in the tool tip for the assignment error.

The erroneous error then **disappears again when you explicitly hit F6 to build**.

Comment: Worth noting, this error is displayed in the ERROR LIST not the OUTPUT(build) window.

Comment: I still don't see the error with your edited code, do you have any add-ins or special settings set?

Comment: what VS plugins do you have running? I can't repro this issue in VS2008 SP1, Win XP SP3 x32. I get the expected error in both cases. FWIW, I'm also running ReSharper 5.0RC EDIT: Ron beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the reported behaviour. If it does in fact reproduce, that's a bug. There is no explicit conversion from string to any user-defined interface.

Please update the question with the version number of the compiler you're using and a small program that reproduces the problem, and I'll get a bug entered into the bug database.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Apparently it does not reproduce on the command line, but is alleged to reproduce in VS2008.

I am unable to reproduce it in the RC build of VS2010, so if this was in fact a bug in VS2008, it's probably been fixed.  I don't have an installation of VS2008 handy right now to test unfortunately.

Regardless, if you're seeing that diagnostic then odds are very good it is simply a bug in the error reporting heuristics in the semantic analyzer. Clearly there is no explicit conversion from string to IFoo.

There is an explicit conversion from any *unsealed* type to any interface type because there could be a derived type which implements the interface. But string is sealed, so the error should simply be "no conversion".

Comment: I just tried to reproduce it on the command line with a few versions of csc.exe, but I cannot reproduce it that way. I only see it when I build with visual studio 2008.

Comment: Correction, I only see it when I trust the errors that visual studio shows automatically *before* I build.

Comment: I can also confirm that I don't see this in VS2010 RC.

Answer (score 5):

I have reproduced this behaviour.
[image: Reproduced.]

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

Microsoft .NET Framework

Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly ripped from [MSDN - Compiler Error CS0266](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z8wb9e4(VS.80).aspx) and [MSDN - explicit (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4(VS.80).aspx).

This error occurs if you have code that attempts to convert two types that cannot be implicitly converted, such as in an assignment of a base type to a derived type that is missing an explicit cast.

The **explicit** keyword declares a user-defined type conversion operator that must be invoked with a cast. For example, this operator converts from a class called Fahrenheit to a class called Celsius:

```
// Must be defined inside a class called Farenheit:
public static explicit operator Celsius(Farenheit f)
{
    return new Celsius((5.0f/9.0f)*(f.degrees-32));
}
```

This conversion operator can be invoked like this:

```
Farenheit f = new Farenheit(100.0f);
Celsius c = (Celsius)f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce this. [CS0029](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzhh5fx5(VS.71).aspx) has only

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type'"

[CS0266](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z8wb9e4(VS.80).aspx) , however, says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

but with `Foo` being an empty class/interface this is not possible, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This Error would occur if you had written:

```
class Foo:IFoo
{
}

interface IFoo
{
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IFoo i = new Foo();
    Foo f = i; // here this message would occur, since IFoo *can* Convert to Foo (Since Foo implements IFoo), but it must be casted explicitly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no explicit way to convert between Foo and string.  However, if you'd like to use that syntax, `Foo foo = "Hello World"` as shorthand you can.  It's accomplished by using the `implicit` operator, as defined here.

It allows you to perform these type of conversions implicitly (hence the name).

To get that type of facade accomplished, here is how you do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ImplicitOperatorTest
{
    class Foo
    {
        private string foo;

        public Foo(string foo)
        {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public static implicit operator string(Foo foo)
        {
            return foo;
        }

        public static implicit operator Foo(string foo)
        {
            return new Foo(foo);
        }
    }

    interface IFoo
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo b = "hello";
        }
    } 
}
```